# QGIS won't save on to SAMBA on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

*I have a couple of QGIS applications (one 3.2.2-Bonn and one 2.18.9 Las Palmas) running on Ubuntu boxes (both 18.04.1 LTS).*

Files are loaded from a SAMBA file share and load fine. But when I try to save the projects, QGIS gives an error:

> couldn't save to the location or there was a zip error

If I try a save-as it says the same thing and creates a file of zero bytes.

Is this a QGIS bug or am I doing wrong when I mount the file share?

I mount them through the 'other locations' tab in the Nautilus.

---

I should have noted that the SAMBA is a windows server and the files were all created in the windows version of QGIS - not sure if that makes a difference.

The terminal command produces this:
[image]

And the error has changed but now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What are the read/write permissions on the drive like?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the error you are seeing?

Comment: Works for me, my SMB share is mounted under the `gvfs` folder in `/run/user` and writing projects is fine. What's the path to the folder you are trying to write?

Comment: Can you run `mount | grep gvfs` and edit your question to show the output - it should be a line with "fuse" in it and some options.